# VB6 pixel based object control Collision Detection

Tags: vb6, collision-detection, collision

Currently, I'm trying to make a simple platformer in VB6 and I'm drawing objects onto the WinForm using BitBlt. I can program rectangular, circular, and line collisions but I want to have pixel-based collision detection.

I assume this can be done with Windows GDI APIs, like MaskBlt, StretchBlt, BitBlt, PltBlt... etc, but I can't get my head around how this would work out.

This is my current VB code for the form:

I currently have 2 PictureBox controls (one for player sprite, one for mask) and one timer control, and another PictureBox which is an obstacle.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim Keys(255) As Boolean

Dim Player As PlayerPos

Private Type PlayerPos
    x As Integer
    y As Integer
End Type

Private Declare Function BitBlt Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDestDC As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hSrcDC As Long, ByVal xSrc As Long, ByVal ySrc As Long, ByVal dwRop As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Keys(KeyCode) = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Keys(KeyCode) = False
End Sub

Private Sub timTick_Timer()
    Cls
    ' Draw collision obj
    BitBlt Me.hDC, 100, 100, pic3.Width \ 15, pic3.Height \ 15, pic3.hDC, 0, 0, vbSrcAnd
    BitBlt Me.hDC, 100, 100, pic3.Width \ 15, pic3.Height \ 15, pic3.hDC, 0, 0, vbSrcPaint
    ' End Draw
    With Player
        Dim Result(0 To 2) As Integer
        If Keys(vbKeyUp) Then .y = .y - 5
        If Keys(vbKeyDown) Then .y = .y + 5
        If Keys(vbKeyRight) Then .x = .x + 5
        If Keys(vbKeyLeft) Then .x = .x - 5
        ' Draw player
        Result(0) = BitBlt(Me.hDC, .x, .y, pic1.Width \ 15, pic1.Height \ 15, pic1.hDC, 0, 0, vbSrcAnd)
        Result(1) = BitBlt(Me.hDC, .x, .y, pic1.Width \ 15, pic1.Height \ 15, pic1Mask.hDC, 0, 0, vbSrcPaint)
        Result(2) = BitBlt(Me.hDC, .x, .y, pic1.Width \ 15, pic1.Height \ 15, pic1.hDC, 0, 0, vbSrcAnd)
        ' End Draw
        lblTest.Caption = Result(0) & Result(1) & Result(2)
    End With
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!